# How to query on custom fields in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to query posts based on a custom field, and then display them in a loop. I've checked and double checked my code against the codex and other sources, but the query still does not appear to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Stripped down to the essentials, my code looks like this:

```
<?php 
  $args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'my_custom_field'
  );
  $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
  <p>Success, we have posts!!!</p>
<?php } else { ?>
  <p>Uh Oh, No posts!!!</p>
<?php } ?>
```

The conditional statement is dropping through and returning "Uh Oh, no posts".

I've checked the postmeta table, and there are definitely posts that contain the meta_key `_my_custom_field`. I have tried the query both with and without leading underscore.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this for search a date between two custom dates field in my custom post type "porfolio", i think that you are in a similar situation:

```
$args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                  'posts_per_page' => '10',
                  'meta_query' => array(
                                        array('key' => 'portfolio_start_date', 'value' => data_to_db2($ricerca_data), 'compare' => '<=', 'type' => 'NUMERIC'),
                                        array('key' => 'portfolio_end_date', 'value' => data_to_db2($ricerca_data), 'compare' => '>=', 'type' => 'NUMERIC')
                                        )
                  );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$post_count = wp_count_posts();
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

// DO WHAT YOU WANT

}

}
```

My advice is to use meta_query in $args array

Comment: thanks firegab, I've tried this approach, but still no success. If I drop the meta_query, and only query for e.g. post_type, the function returns the expected posts. So there must be an error with how I've set up or am querying the metakeys. I'm unsure how to debug this though. Any advice?

Comment: in your mysql table wp_postmeta the field result saved correctly?

Comment: hi firegab, yes it is saved correctly. I just tried creating several more posts and pages with this custom field, and suddenly the query is working. Confused as to what's changed, but happy it is now working. Thanks for your help

Comment: Good! it was a pleasure!